# Elm beginner's question: Html input seems to be preventing model property update

Tags: elm

I have created a simple Elm program that takes in an input via an Html input and, when a submit button is clicked, updates an Html text with a based on the input value.

In addition there is a reset button which resets the model to its initial value.

What I am finding is that, when reset is clicked, the Html text is reset to its initial value however the Html input is not.

What am I missing here?

```
module Main exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, button, div, text, input)
import Html.Events exposing (onClick, onInput)

type alias Model =
    { name : String,
      message : String
    }

initialModel : Model
    initialModel =
    { name = "",
      message = "" }

type Msg
    = SubmitName
    | ResetName
    | UpdateName String

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        UpdateName text -> 
            { model | name = text }

        SubmitName ->
            { model | 
            message = 
               if model.name =="Dugald McDougall" then 
                   "What a great name!"
               else 
                   "Meh..."
            }

       ResetName ->
           initialModel

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input [ onInput UpdateName ] []
        , div [] [ button [ onClick SubmitName ] [ text "Submit" ]
        , button [ onClick ResetName ] [ text "Reset" ] 
        , div[] [ text <| model.message ] ]
        ]

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.sandbox
        { init = initialModel
         , view = view
         , update = update
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `input` keeps track of its own value in the DOM, and it does not know about the current value in the model. You need to use a "controlled" `input` where the value is forced to stay in sync with the model.

```
import Html.Attributes exposing (value)

...

input [ onInput UpdateName, value model.name ] []
```

Whenever the model changes, the Elm virtual DOM updates the input in the real DOM so that it has the new value.